# Use Filter() on a particular row of a 2 dimensional array (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to have a "unique" array of another multi-dimensional array, the array looks something like this:

```
var bigArray = Array(
                ["text", "text", "A", 1, 2],
                ["text", "text", "S", 3, 4],
                ["text", "text", "S", 4, 4],
                ["text", "text", "S", 5, 7],
                ["text", "text", "S", 2, 1],
                ["text", "text", "S", 1, 0]
            );
```

The result should be something like

`uniqueArray = [A, S]`

And this is the filter function I have atm:

```
var uniqueArray = bigArray.filter(function(item, i, ar){ return ar.indexOf(item) === i; });
```

The function gives me ALL the unique values in the big array, but I only need the unique values from row[2].
I guess the parameters must be tweaked a bit from the filter function but I don't understand them well.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
var bigArray = Array(
  ["text", "text", "A", 1, 2],
  ["text", "text", "S", 3, 4],
  ["text", "text", "S", 4, 4],
  ["text", "text", "S", 5, 7],
  ["text", "text", "S", 2, 1],
  ["text", "text", "S", 1, 0]
);

var newArray = []
bigArray.forEach(function(item) {
  if (newArray.indexOf(item[2]) == -1) {
    newArray.push(item[2])
  }
})
console.log(newArray)
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/x7bsxy1L/)

Answer (score 4):

[`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns items if the array and not parts of the inner array. Therefore, you need a different approach, by mapping only the wanted value and fillter later.

With ES6 you could map the wanted column and use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for unique values.

```js
var bigArray = [["text", "text", "A", 1, 2], ["text", "text", "S", 3, 4], ["text", "text", "S", 4, 4], ["text", "text", "S", 5, 7], ["text", "text", "S", 2, 1], ["text", "text", "S", 1, 0]],
    result = [...new Set(bigArray.map(a => a[2]))];
    
console.log(result);
```

ES5 with a hash table.

```js
var bigArray = [["text", "text", "A", 1, 2], ["text", "text", "S", 3, 4], ["text", "text", "S", 4, 4], ["text", "text", "S", 5, 7], ["text", "text", "S", 2, 1], ["text", "text", "S", 1, 0]],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result;

bigArray.forEach(function (a) {
    hash[a[2]] = true;
});
result = Object.keys(hash);
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks Nina for your answer, but it's too complex for me I'm sorry :p I will go for the answer here below from @brk it's more readable and I understand what it does. Thanks for your time anyway.